# Select-String -pattern wholeword

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find all the file starting with dt and extension c* that have this precise string inside "CheckAnagrEA"
The problem is that this cmdlet returns also files that have "CheckAnagrEAInsert" etc.

Here's the code:

```
$cnt = Get-ChildItem $githubfolder -Filter DT*.c* -Recurse -Exclude *.sql | Select-String -pattern "CheckAnagrEA"
```

How can i find ONLY the wholeword?

Comment: Is `CheckAnagrEA` a folder name?

Comment: Is the whole word a group of symbols contiguous only with ^ (beginning of line), $ (end of line) and space?

Comment: CheckAnagrEA is the name of the stored procedure i'm looking for

Answer (score 10):

Try the pattern

```
\bCheckAnagrEA\b
```

`\b` matches a word boundary. See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w.aspx).